# How to mock a response from MatDialog sent from afterClosed in Angular unit tests?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, mat-dialog

I am trying to write some unit tests for MatDialog. What I am trying to do is to mock the response from the dialog and test, if it was correctly handled by the component.

In my component, I should get a `Map<string, any>` from the closed dialog and set them into `myData` Map.

**my.component.ts**

```js
export class MyComponent {

  public myData = new Map<string, any>();

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  public openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(LoadDataComponent);
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(response => {
        response.data.forEach(item => {
            this.myData.set(item.id, item);
        });
    });
  }
}
```

**my.component.spec.ts**

```js
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
  const responseMock = new Map<string, any>();
  
  class DialogMock {
    open(): any {
      return {
        afterClosed: () => of(responseMock)
      };
    }
  }

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        MyComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: MatDialog, useClass: DialogMock },
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.myData = new Map<string, any>();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    responseMock.set('test', {value: 'test'});
    responseMock.set('test2', {value: 'test2'});
  });



  it('should get data from dialog', fakeAsync(() => {
  
    spyOn(component.dialog, 'open').and.returnValue({
        afterClosed: () => of(responseMock)
    } as MatDialogRef<typeof component>);

    component.openDialog();
    expect(component.myData.size).toBe(2);
  }));

});
```

In my spec file I have created some `responseMock` and I am trying to use it as a response but my test is simply failing:

> Chrome Headless 91.0.4472.164 (Windows 10) ERROR
> An error was thrown in afterAll
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
> Chrome 91.0.4472.164 (Windows 10) MyComponent should get data from dialog FAILED
> Error: Expected 0 to be 2.

How can I mock a response from MatDialog in my unit test so it will be correctly handled by `MyComponent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the method under the test, there is a loop against response data: `response.data.forEach`. According to mock setup, the value if the `response` would be `const responseMock = new Map<string, any>();`. It doesn't contain the `data` property. To fix it you might change the response mock to

```js
const responseMock = {data: new Map<string, any>()};
```

Comment: That was the case. Thank you, I didn't notice that :)